# Parse - imageView as PFFile won't load

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I don't understand what is going on. I have an image saved as a PFFile in Parse. I can see it and I know it is there. I want to have it as a cell image. The rest of the code below works fine and the memory addresses of PFFile also print. textLabel and detailTextLabel also fine but the images won't show (even if I delete 'loadInBackground'). Any ideas?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
     cell = PFTableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    if let name = object?["name"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
    }

    if let artist = object?["artist"] as? String {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = artist
    }

    if let artwork = object?["artwork"] as? PFFile {
        println("we've got an artwork image \(artwork)")
        //cell!.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")
        cell.imageView?.file = artwork
        cell.imageView?.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse just saves an reference to the image in the table, you will have to do another async call to retrieve the message.:

```
let artwork = object?["artwork"] as PFFile
artwork.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    if let imageData = imageData {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your code should work but still doesn't. The parse document doesn't recommend getting the image in the background. Actually, since I am using a PFQueryTableViewController, all I should do is set "setImageKey" to "artwork", which I have done but it still doesn't load the image.

Comment: I deleted the prototype cell from the storyboard and it worked. I didn't need to fetch it in the background by the way.